# Receiving Empty email from Submit form every day around the same time

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am receiving empty email from Submit form every day around the same time.

Form Code :

```
                     <div class="form">
                            <h4 class="h-light text-center">Submit a Query</h4>

                             <form class="form-horizontal" action="sendemail.php" method="post"  id="contact_form">

                                    <!-- Text input-->

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>  
                                      <div class="col-sm-10 inputGroupContainer">
                                      <div class="input-group">
                                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                      <input  name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control input-text"  type="text" required>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <!-- Text input-->
                                           <div class="form-group">
                                      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">E-Mail</label>  
                                        <div class="col-sm-10 inputGroupContainer">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                                      <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control input-text"  type="email" required>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <!-- Text input-->

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone #</label>  
                                        <div class="col-sm-10 inputGroupContainer">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                                      <input name="phone" placeholder="(123)456-7890" class="form-control input-text" type="text" required>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <!-- Text area -->

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10 inputGroupContainer">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                                                <textarea class="form-control input-text text-area" name="message" placeholder="Enter your massage for us here. We will get back to you." required></textarea>
                                      </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><img src="media/home/captcha.png"></label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <!-- Success message -->
                                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.</div>

                                    <!-- Button -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"></label>
                                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <button type="submit" class="input-btn" >Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>

                                </form>
```

sendemail.php Code:

```
   <?php

    /* These are the variable that tell the subject of the email and where the email will be sent.*/

    $emailSubject = 'New query !';
    $mailto = 'xxx@domain.in';

    /* These will gather what the user has typed into the field. */

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];


    /* This takes the information and lines it up the way you want it to be sent in the email. */

    $body = <<<EOD
    <br><hr><br>
    Name: $name <br>
    Email Address: $email <br>
    Phone Number: $phone <br>
    Message: $message<br>

    EOD;

    $headers = "From:domain.in<xxx@domain.in>\r\n"; // This takes the email and displays it as who this email is from.
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; // This tells the server to turn the coding into the text.
    //$success = mail($mailto, $emailSubject, $body, $headers); // This tells the server what to send.

    if(mail($mailto, $emailSubject, $body, $headers))
           {
                    echo "Your query has been submitted successfully. ";
                    echo '<a href="index.html">Go Back</a>';
           }
         else
         {
           echo "Failure";
         }
    ?>
```

I have no idea what is going on, the code seems to be fine, but still i am receiving that empty email only with the field name like...
Name :
Email Address :
Phone Number :
Message :

But no information filled in it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you add some validation code so that it checks that the form is filled out before it emails you?

Comment: How can i do that? i have used required tag in bootstrap for the validation.

Comment: Please help me still i am receiving the blank email on the same time

Comment: Well, the email is not being generated from this code. It must be getting sent from somewhere else. If you used the code in your answer below which i said should work there's no way it can send a blank email. Is the subject blank as well?

Answer (score 0):

Validate the input on the PHP side before you send the email. eg:

```
$valid = true;

$name = $_POST['name'];
if(empty($name))
{
    echo('Please enter your name');
    $valid = false;
}

// Repeat for other fields

if($valid)
{
    // Send the email
}
```

Comment: I tried the one i have sent yesterday, but the code is not working

Answer (score 0):

I am not so good with PHP, please let me know if it correct.. Thank you

```
<?php

    /* These are the variable that tell the subject of the email and where the email will be sent.*/

    $emailSubject = 'New query!';
    $mailto = 'xxx@domain.in';

    /* These will gather what the user has typed into the fieled. */

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];


    /* This takes the information and lines it up the way you want it to be sent in the email. */

    $body = <<<EOD
    <br><hr><br>
    Name: $name <br>
    Email Address: $email <br>
    Phone Number: $phone <br>
    Message: $message<br>

    EOD;

    $headers = "From:domain.in<info@domain.in>\r\n"; // This takes the email and displays it as who this email is from.
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; // This tells the server to turn the coding into the text.
    //$success = mail($mailto, $emailSubject, $body, $headers); // This tells the server what to send.


    $valid = true;

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    if(empty($name))
    {
        echo('Please enter your name');
        $valid = false;
    }

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if(empty($email))
    {
        echo('Please enter your email');
        $valid = false;
    }

    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    if(empty($phone))
    {
        echo('Please enter your Phone number');
        $valid = false;
    }

    $message = $_POST['message'];
    if(empty($message))
    {
        echo('Please enter your message');
        $valid = false;
    }


    if($valid)
    {
        if(mail($mailto, $emailSubject, $body, $headers))
           {
                    echo "Your query has been submitted successfully. ";
                    echo '<a href="index.html">Go Back</a>';
           }

    }
    else
         {
           echo "Failure";
         }

    i
    ?>
```

Comment: Yes, that should work except you have an "i" at the end which will cause a syntax error.  Also you will want to add line breaks to all the echo statements otherwise it's going to output like this: "Please enter your namePlease enter your emailPlease enter your Phone numberPlease enter your messageFailure"

Answer (score 0):

Should be working now?

```
$valid = true;

$name = $_POST['name'];
if(empty($name))
{
    echo('Please enter your name');
    $valid = false;
}
<br/>

$email = $_POST['email'];
if(empty($email))
{
    echo('Please enter your email');
    $valid = false;
}
<br/>

$phone = $_POST['phone'];
if(empty($phone))
{
    echo('Please enter your Phone number');
    $valid = false;
}
<br/>

$message = $_POST['message'];
if(empty($message))
{
    echo('Please enter your message');
    $valid = false;
}
<br/>

if($valid)
{
    if(mail($mailto, $emailSubject, $body, $headers))
       {
                echo "Your query has been submitted successfully. ";
                echo '<a href="index.html">Go Back</a>';
       }

}
else
     {
       echo "Failure";
     }


?>
```

Comment: What is this? This code won't work. You have HTML in PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for whether $_Post is empty is the usual and logical way to go.

But for someone who is curious about why the same empty email is being sent to you everyday (usually it's some kind of bot) why not add the following fields in your message body so you know what's happening.

This way you learn how the web works better too.

For example

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // for IP address
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // get browser info
```

and you add above info to your message body so you know what's going on.

Comment: After adding this code, how will i recognize that the empty email i received was from the bot?

Comment: It depends, usually if it's normal person it will return chrome, windows, mozilla etc information. This is for investigative purpose and does not stop empty emails from coming in.The best approach is still to check whether $_POST is empty before a email is sent in the future. And even a better one is to check front end.